# Dealing with changed rows during storing on a QTreeView with QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, qsqltablemodel

I have a `QTreeView` which displays a result from SQLite via `QSqlTableModel` (PyQt5 version: 5.13.0).
I want to change some values via a detail-dialog which populates the data via `modelTable.record()`.
Therefore I set the edit strategy to `OnManualSubmit` and store the values later on with `submitAll()`.

Problem: I write the changed values to Db with `record.setValue()`.
But: if I change a value twice, *it's current row number may change*.

Reproduce:

1. Run the code below
2. Double-click on last row, cell with name "a"; change name to "z" and
   push the "Save" button.
3. The dialog remains open; the last row becomes the very first row.
   That's OK, based on the current sorting order! Now change the entry
   back to "a" and push the "Save" button again.

The entry will be applied to the last row. -> OK.

But the old values remain in the first row! Now I have the first and last row identically and the old values from previously first row are lost!
Sqlite Error `UNIQUE constraint failed: <id> Unable to fetch row` occurs also.

Expectation: when pressing "Save" the 2nd time, the values from the dialog are displayed in the last row and the old values from row 1 are correct.

(You'd get this if you push the "refresh" btn or close the dlg between the 2 modification operations.)

Full working code example:

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtSql

TRACE = True

MY_TABLE = "person"
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")

modelQuery = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
modelTable = QtSql.QSqlRelationalTableModel()

g_hits_count = 0
g_total_count = 0
g_selected_count = 0

def trace(message):
    if TRACE:
        print(message)

def _human_key(key):
    parts = re.split(r'(\d*\.\d+|\d+)', key)
    return tuple((e.swapcase() if i % 2 == 0 else float(e))
            for i, e in enumerate(parts))

class dlgDetail(QtWidgets.QDialog):        
    def __init__(self, parent, cur_row, row_id):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)        
        self.setModal(False)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        self.parent = self.parent()
        trace(f"dlgDetail was called with cur_row: {cur_row}")
        self.cur_row = cur_row
        self.row_id = row_id

        self.setupUi(self)

        # connect signals
        self.accepted.connect(self.dlgDetail_accepted)
        self.rejected.connect(self.dlgDetail_rejected)
        self.pbNew.clicked.connect(self.on_pbNew_clicked)
        self.pbSave.clicked.connect(self.on_pbSave_clicked)
        self.pbSave.setDefault(True)
        self.pbDel.clicked.connect(self.on_pbDel_clicked)
        self.pbCancel.clicked.connect(self.on_pbCancel_clicked)

        if cur_row > -1:  # existing record            
            # load selected record        
            # get current selection (could be filtered)
            sourceIdx = self.parent.treeView.model().mapToSource(self.parent.treeView.currentIndex())            
            self.cur_row = sourceIdx.row()
            trace(f"got my own cur_row -> {self.cur_row}")
            record_display = modelTable.record(self.cur_row)            

            persId = record_display.value("persId")
            lastName = record_display.value("lastName")
            firstName = record_display.value("firstName")
            country = record_display.value("name")

            # display record
            self.efId.setText(persId)        
            self.efLastName.setText(lastName)
            self.efFirstName.setText(firstName)
            self.populate_comboBox(self.cmbCountry, country)

        else:  # new record
            # get next free row id        
            modelQuery.setQuery("SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM person")
            self.row_id = modelQuery.data(modelQuery.index(0, 0))

            self.efId.setText("new" + str(self.row_id))
            self.efLastName.setText("new" + str(self.row_id))
            self.efFirstName.setText("new" + str(self.row_id))
            self.populate_comboBox(self.cmbCountry, 0)

        self.show()

    def get_geometry(self):
        return self.geometry().x(), self.geometry().y(), self.geometry().width(), self.geometry().height()

    def center(self, offset):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
        frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft()+QtCore.QPoint(frameGm.topLeft().x(), frameGm.topLeft().y()+offset))

    def clear_inputs(self):
        self.efId.setText("new")        
        self.efLastName.setText("new")
        self.efFirstName.setText("new")
        self.cmbCountry.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def setupUi(self, parent):
        vBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        form = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()

        lblId = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lblId.setText("ID:")              
        form.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, lblId)

        self.efId = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)        
        form.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.efId)

        lblLastName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lblLastName.setText("Last Name:")        
        form.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, lblLastName)

        self.efLastName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)        
        form.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.efLastName)

        lblFirstName = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lblFirstName.setText("First Name:")        
        form.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, lblFirstName)

        self.efFirstName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)                
        form.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.efFirstName)

        lblCountry = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        lblCountry.setText("Country:")        
        form.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, lblCountry)                    

        self.cmbCountry = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)        
        form.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.cmbCountry)

        vBox.addLayout(form)

        # command buttons
        hBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)        
        hBox.addItem(spacerItem)

        self.pbNew = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pbNew.setText("New")
        hBox.addWidget(self.pbNew)        

        self.pbSave = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pbSave.setText("Save")
        hBox.addWidget(self.pbSave)

        self.pbDel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pbDel.setText("Del")
        hBox.addWidget(self.pbDel)

        self.pbCancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pbCancel.setText("Cancel")
        hBox.addWidget(self.pbCancel)

        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        hBox.addItem(spacerItem1)

        vBox.addLayout(hBox)

    def populate_comboBox(self, comboBox, country):        
        model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
        model.setTable("country")
        model.select()

        comboBox.setModel(model)
        comboBox.setModelColumn(model.fieldIndex("name"))

        # select the person's set country        
        index = comboBox.findText(str(country), QtCore.Qt.MatchFixedString)
        if index >= 0:            
            comboBox.setCurrentIndex(index)

    def dlgDetail_accepted(self):
        pass

    def dlgDetail_rejected(self):
        pass

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pbCancel_clicked(self):        
        self.reject()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pbSave_clicked(self):
        trace(f"saving for row_id: {self.row_id}")
        country_id = self.cmbCountry.currentIndex()
        self.cur_row, self.row_id = self.parent.update_record(self.cur_row, self.row_id, self.efId.text(), self.efLastName.text(), self.efFirstName.text(), country_id)        

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pbNew_clicked(self):
        self.accept()        
        self.parent.new_record()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pbDel_clicked(self):        
        self.parent.del_record()
        self.accept()        

class FilterHeader(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    filterActivated = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)
        self._editors = []
        self._padding = 4
        self.setStretchLastSection(True)        
        self.setDefaultAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.sectionResized.connect(self.adjustPositions)
        parent.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.adjustPositions)

    def setFilterBoxes(self, count):
        while self._editors:
            editor = self._editors.pop()
            editor.deleteLater()
        for index in range(count):
            editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.parent())            
            editor.setPlaceholderText('Filter')
            editor.setClearButtonEnabled(True)            
            editor.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)

            self._editors.append(editor)
        self.adjustPositions()

    def textChanged(self):        
        self.filterActivated.emit()

    def sizeHint(self):
        size = super().sizeHint()
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            size.setHeight(size.height() + height + self._padding)
        return size

    def updateGeometries(self):
        if self._editors:
            height = self._editors[0].sizeHint().height()
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, height + self._padding)
        else:
            self.setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        super().updateGeometries()
        self.adjustPositions()

    def adjustPositions(self):
        for index, editor in enumerate(self._editors):
            height = editor.sizeHint().height()
            editor.move(
                self.sectionPosition(index) - self.offset() + 2,
                height + (self._padding // 2))
            editor.resize(self.sectionSize(index), height)

    def filterText(self, index):        
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            return self._editors[index].text()
        return ''

    def setFilterText(self, index, text):
        if 0 <= index < len(self._editors):
            self._editors[index].setText(text)

    def clearFilters(self):        
        for editor in self._editors:
            editor.clear()


class HumanProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):            
    def lessThan(self, source_left, source_right):
        data_left = source_left.data()
        data_right = source_right.data()
        if type(data_left) == type(data_right) == str:
            return _human_key(data_left) < _human_key(data_right)
        return super(HumanProxyModel, self).lessThan(source_left, source_right)    

    @property
    def filters(self):        
        if not hasattr(self, "_filters"):
            self._filters = []        
        return self._filters

    @filters.setter
    def filters(self, filters):
        self._filters = filters
        self.invalidateFilter()

        global g_hits_count
        g_hits_count = self.rowCount()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):        
        for i, text in self.filters:            
            if 0 <= i < self.sourceModel().columnCount():
                ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, i, sourceParent)
                data = ix.data()                
                if text not in data:                
                    return False

        return True                

class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    cur_row = -1
    row_id = -1

    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("SqlTableModel Test")
        self.setupUi()
        self.setGeometry(300,200,700,500)

        self.treeView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.item_selection_changed_slot)
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_treeView_doubleClicked)
        self.center()
        self.show()        

    def closeEvent(self, event):                        
        self.deleteLater()

    def new_record(self):
        self.cur_row = -1
        self.row_id = -1

        dlgDetail(self, self.cur_row, self.row_id)

        self.updateStatus()        

    def update_record(self, cur_row, row_id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id):
        trace("update_record() called. row: {cur_row}, id: {row_id}")
        record = modelTable.record()
        row = modelTable.rowCount()

        if cur_row > -1:  # existing entry
            trace(f"storing existing -> {lastName} (id: {row_id}) on row {cur_row}")
            row = cur_row            
            record.setValue("id", row_id)
        else:
            trace(f"storing new -> {lastName} (id: {row_id}) on row {cur_row}")
            row = modelTable.rowCount()            
            modelTable.insertRow(row) 

        record.setValue("persId", persId)
        record.setValue("lastName", lastName)
        record.setValue("firstName", firstName)
        record.setValue("name", country_id)

        # Update Model        
        modelTable.setRecord(row, record)        

        # Update Database
        if modelTable.submitAll():         
            trace("success on storing data.")            
        else:
            print("error on storing data: ", modelTable.lastError().text())

        if cur_row == -1:
            # get used row_id
            record_display = modelTable.record(row)
            row_id = record_display.value("persId")
            trace(f"   got new_row id from database: {row_id} after save.")

        self.updateStatus()

        # Remember current row data
        self.cur_row = row
        self.row_id = row_id

        print (f"returning row: {row}, row_id: {row_id}")

        return row, row_id

    def edit_record(self, sourceIdx):        
        if not sourceIdx:
            sourceIdx = self.treeView.currentIndex()

        # check if multiple selected rows exist
        if len(self.treeView.selectionModel().selectedRows()) > 1:            
            reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, f"Editing multiple records",
                                               f"Do you want to edit *all* the selected records?\rYes = Edit all records, No = Edit only current record",
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
                                               QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes)
            if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                # load all selected rows
                index_list = []                                                          
                for model_index in self.treeView.selectionModel().selectedRows():       
                    index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(model_index)         
                    index_list.append(index)                                             

                offset = 0
                for index in index_list:                    
                    cur_row = index.row()
                    ix = self.treeView.model().index(index.row(), 0)  # column which contains the id            
                    row_id = ix.data()

                    dlgDetail(self, cur_row, row_id)
                    offset += 20
                return True

        # only single selection
        trace("single selection")
        self.cur_row = sourceIdx.row()
        ix = self.treeView.model().index(sourceIdx.row(), 0)  # column which contains the id            
        self.row_id = ix.data()

        dlgDetail(self, self.cur_row, self.row_id)

        self.updateStatus()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_treeView_doubleClicked(self, index):        
        self.edit_record(index)

    def handleFilterActivated(self):        
        header = self.treeView.header()
        filters = []
        for i in range(header.count()):
            text = header.filterText(i)
            if text:
                filters.append((i, text))
        proxy = self.treeView.model()        
        proxy.filters = filters

        self.updateStatus()

    QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def item_selection_changed_slot(self):
        selected = self.treeView.selectionModel()
        indexes = selected.selectedIndexes()

        global g_selected_count        
        g_selected_count = len(selected.selectedRows())

        sourceIdx = self.treeView.currentIndex()
        trace(f"sourceIdx.row() -> {sourceIdx.row()}")
        ix = self.treeView.model().index(sourceIdx.row(), 0)  # column which contains the id

        self.cur_row = sourceIdx.row()        
        self.row_id = ix.data()

        trace(f"setting cur_row to -> {self.cur_row}")
        trace(f"setting row_id to -> {self.row_id}")

        record = modelTable.record(self.cur_row)        

        persId = record.value("persId")
        lastName = record.value("lastName")
        firstName = record.value("firstName")
        country = record.value("name")

        trace(f"self.cur_row: {self.cur_row}")
        trace(f"self.row_id : {self.row_id}")
        trace(f"persId: {persId}")
        trace(f"lastName: {lastName}")

        self.updateStatus()

    def refresh(self):
        cur_row = -1
        row_id = -1
        self.clear_all_filters()        

        modelTable.select() # fetch the data of the table into the model

        self.treeView.sortByColumn(2, QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)

        self.updateStatus()

        self.statusBar.showMessage(f"data reloaded.")

    def updateStatus(self):
        global g_hits_count, g_total_count, g_selected_count


        sStatusText = f"Selected: {str(g_selected_count)} / Hits: {str(g_hits_count)} / Total: {str(g_total_count)}      |      Current row: {self.cur_row}, row id: {self.row_id}"

        self.statusBar.showMessage(sStatusText)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, eventQKeyEvent):                
        key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
        modifiers = QtWidgets.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()
        if modifiers == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier and key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:            
                self.clear_all_filters()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()

        modifiers = QtWidgets.QApplication.keyboardModifiers()

        if modifiers != QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
            focus_obj = self.focusWidget()

            if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:  
                if type(focus_obj) == QtWidgets.QTreeView:
                    self.edit_record(self.treeView.currentIndex())


            elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:            
                if type(focus_obj) == QtWidgets.QLineEdit:
                    focus_obj.clear()                

    def clear_all_filters(self):        
        # clear all inputs of type QLineEdit
        lineEdits = self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        for lineEdit in lineEdits:           
            lineEdit.clear()

    def center(self):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
        frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft())

    def setupUi(self):
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        hBox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)

        self.treeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)       

        self.treeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)                       
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)        
        self.treeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.treeView.header().setStretchLastSection(True)


        hBox.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        header = FilterHeader(self.treeView)        
        self.treeView.setHeader(header)
        self.treeView.sortByColumn(2, QtCore.Qt.DescendingOrder)

        # StatusBar
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        # ToolBar
        exitAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Exit", self, shortcut="Ctrl+Q", triggered=QtWidgets.qApp.quit)        
        newRecordAct = QtWidgets.QAction("New", self, shortcut="Ctrl+N", triggered=self.new_record)
        editRecordAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Edit", self, shortcut="Return", triggered=self.edit_record)                
        refreshAct = QtWidgets.QAction("Refresh", self, shortcut="F5", triggered=self.refresh)        

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAct)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addAction(newRecordAct)
        self.toolbar.addAction(editRecordAct)        
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.toolbar.addAction(refreshAct)

        modelTable.setTable(MY_TABLE)

        modelTable.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "row id")
        modelTable.setHeaderData(1, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "ID")
        modelTable.setHeaderData(2, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Last Name")
        modelTable.setHeaderData(3, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "First Name")
        modelTable.setHeaderData(4, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, "Country")

        modelTable.setRelation(4, QtSql.QSqlRelation("country", "id", "name"))

        modelTable.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnManualSubmit)

        self.treeView.setModel(modelTable) # display data of the SQLTableModel into the QTreeView
        if not TRACE:
            self.treeView.setColumnHidden(0, True)

        # enable human sorting                
        proxy = HumanProxyModel(self)
        proxy.setSourceModel(modelTable)
        self.treeView.setModel(proxy)

        # enable filtering
        header.setFilterBoxes(modelTable.columnCount())
        header.filterActivated.connect(self.handleFilterActivated)

        # update counters
        global g_total_count, g_hits_count
        g_total_count = modelTable.rowCount()
        g_hits_count = g_total_count
        self.updateStatus()


def create_sample_data():     
    modelQuery.setQuery("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country (                                    
                                    id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                                    name TEXT
                                    )""")

    modelQuery.setQuery("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
                                   id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                                   persId     TEXT,
                                   lastName   TEXT,
                                   firstName  TEXT,
                                   country_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 3,
              FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES country(id)
                                   )""")

    # create some sample data for our model
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (0, 'None')")    
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Angola')")    
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Serbia')")
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO country (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Georgia')")

    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id) VALUES (1, '1001', 'a', 'Robert', 1)")
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id) VALUES (2, '1002', 'b', 'Brad', 2)")
    modelQuery.setQuery("INSERT INTO person (id, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id) VALUES (3, '1003', 'c', 'Angelina', 3)")

if __name__ == '__main__':                         
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)             

    create_sample_data()

    window = winMain()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the visual row since it can change when the row is reordered, instead you should look for some persistent element, a possible solution is to use a QPersintenModelIndex.

In the following code I implement that logic:

```py
class dlgDetail(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, index):
        super(dlgDetail, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setModal(False)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        self.index = index
        self.parent = self.parent()
        trace(f"dlgDetail was called with cur_row: {index.row()}")

        self.setupUi(self)

        # connect signals
        self.accepted.connect(self.dlgDetail_accepted)
        self.rejected.connect(self.dlgDetail_rejected)
        self.pbNew.clicked.connect(self.on_pbNew_clicked)
        self.pbSave.clicked.connect(self.on_pbSave_clicked)
        self.pbSave.setDefault(True)
        self.pbDel.clicked.connect(self.on_pbDel_clicked)
        self.pbCancel.clicked.connect(self.on_pbCancel_clicked)

        if self.index.isValid():
            record_display = modelTable.record(self.index.row())

            persId = record_display.value("persId")
            lastName = record_display.value("lastName")
            firstName = record_display.value("firstName")
            country = record_display.value("name")

            self.efId.setText(persId)
            self.efLastName.setText(lastName)
            self.efFirstName.setText(firstName)
            self.populate_comboBox(self.cmbCountry, country)
        else:

            modelQuery.setQuery("SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM person")
            self.row_id = modelQuery.data(modelQuery.index(0, 0))

            self.efId.setText("new" + str(self.row_id))
            self.efLastName.setText("new" + str(self.row_id))
            self.efFirstName.setText("new" + str(self.row_id))
            self.populate_comboBox(self.cmbCountry, 0)

        self.show()

    # ...

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pbSave_clicked(self):
        self.parent.update_record(
            self.index,
            self.efId.text(),
            self.efLastName.text(),
            self.efFirstName.text(),
            self.cmbCountry.currentIndex()
        )
    # ...

class winMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # ...

    def new_record(self):
        dlgDetail(self, QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex())
        self.updateStatus()

    def update_record(self, index, persId, lastName, firstName, country_id):
        if index.isValid():
            row = index.row()
            record = modelTable.record(row)
        else:
            row = modelTable.rowCount()
            modelTable.insertRow(row)
            record = modelTable.record()
        record.setValue("persId", persId)
        record.setValue("lastName", lastName)
        record.setValue("firstName", firstName)
        record.setValue("name", country_id)
        modelTable.setRecord(row, record)
        # Update Database
        if modelTable.submitAll():
            trace("success on storing data.")
        else:
            print("error on storing data: ", modelTable.lastError().text())

        if not index.isValid():
            record_display = modelTable.record(0)
            row_id = record_display.value("persId")
            trace(f"   got new_row id from database: {row_id} after save.")
        self.updateStatus()

    def edit_record(self, sourceIdx):

        if len(self.treeView.selectionModel().selectedRows()) > 1:
            reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
                self,
                f"Editing multiple records",
                f"Do you want to edit *all* the selected records?\rYes = Edit all records, No = Edit only current recaord",
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes
                | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No
                | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel,
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes,
            )
            if reply == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                for proxy_index in self.treeView.selectionModel().selectedRows():
                    proxy_model = proxy_index.model()
                    index = proxy_model.mapToSource(proxy_index)
                    p_index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
                    dlgDetail(self, p_index)
                return True

        if not sourceIdx:
            sourceIdx = self.treeView.currentIndex()
            if not sourceIdx.isValid():
                trace("not selection")
                return False
        # only single selection
        trace("single selection")
        proxy_model = sourceIdx.model()
        index = proxy_model.mapToSource(sourceIdx)
        dlgDetail(self, index)
        self.updateStatus()
```

<sup>The full solution is [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/57201204)</sup>